# How to display message if User doesn't have created list items

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Im using the default web application mvc 5 template project with asp.net identity.
I have a Movie.cs model, and associated each User to have a Movies list, so when you register you can go and add movies in the list with CRUD, and im showing them on the home page.

[image]

my viewmodel:

```
@model MovieApp.ViewModels.UserMovieViewModel
@using MovieApp.Models;

<div class="row" style="margin-top:60px">
    @using (ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        if (db.Users.Any())
        {
            foreach (var _user in Model.ApplicationUser)
            {
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h3 class="panel-title">@_user.UserName</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <ul>
                                @foreach (var _movie in _user.Movies.Where(x => x.ApplicationUserID == _user.Id))
                                {
                                    <li>@_movie.MovieName</li>                                        
                                }
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        }
        else
        {
            <h2 class="alert alert-danger text-center">No movie lists</h2>
        }
    }

</div>
```

If i have a user that hasn't added any movies in the list, then i got null exception error for this line:

```
@foreach (var _movie in _user.Movies.Where(x => x.ApplicationUserID == _user.Id))
```

so how to display message (like in the picture below)in the list under each user if the user hasn't created any movies?

[image]

Comment: Make sure in your ApplicationUser model you are initializing the underlying variable for the Movies property to new List<Movie>(); to make sure it is never null.

Comment: Just do what Kevin said so it will operate on an empty Enumerable and then do: `if (!_user.Movies.Any())` with your message.

Comment: @Kevin In my appuser model i have a property for movies like this:
public List<Movie> Movies { get; set; }, so i don't know if i'm doing this right but when i change it to public List<Movie> Movies = new List<Movie>();
then i don't get any list in my view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this by checking whether there is any movie or not inside `.panel-body` like this:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    @if(_user.Movies != null && _user.Movies.Any()) {
        <ul>
            @foreach (var _movie in _user.Movies.Where(x => x.ApplicationUserID == _user.Id)) 
            {
                <li>@_movie.MovieName</li>
            }
        </ul>
    } 
    else 
    {
        <p>No movies...</p>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need the `Any` check for true. Movies will be an empty enumerable so it will not render anything anyway. Only need one check for not true and display message.

Comment: Well, yeah. You could perhaps invert the statement and do `if (!_user.Movies.Any()) { <p>No movies...</p> }`. :)

Comment: @mwilczynski I tried this but im still getting null exception for this line
if (_user.Movies.Any())

Comment: @john It means that _user.Movies could be null too. I've updated my answer to check for `_user.Movies != null`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a backing variable for your Movies property and initialize it to an empty list:

```
IList<Movie> _movies = new List<Movie>();
```

Then your property definition becomes:

```
IList<Movie> Movies
{
    get
    {
        return _movies;
    }

    set
    {
        _movies = value;
    }
}
```

This will ensure that if a user has not yet added any movies, the Movies property will return an empty list of movies instead of null.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a condition in the view

```
if (_user.Movies.Any())
{
    your foreach
}
else
{
    your message
}
```

Comment: This will loop through all movies though and then check if count is more than 0.

Use `Any`

Comment: `Any` returns a bool not an int, don't need `> 0`. I'd edit it but I can't due to limit.

Comment: That was a lame mistake srry